# Setting a DFP Ad / Creative to Display:None

Tags: css, google-dfp

If you set a DFP (Google Ads) ad / creative to `display:none` so it is invisible. Will it still get impressions? So say I have 31 DFP ads, one is set to `display:block` and the other 30 are set to `display:none`.. will each one of the 30 ads that are invisible get a view / impression? And say I set the 30 ads to `display:none` and then switch them over to `display:block` when the viewers browser width exceeds 600px...  Will the impressions only count until the ads are turned into `display:block`?  Or how would this whole display none with DFP situation work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, if you set the adunit to display none the JavaScript is still executed and the ad is still loaded into the page, hence it counts as an impression. I am pretty sure this will be against the Google DFP terms of service and would recommend not taking this approach.

Answer (score 0):

According to the responsive ad unit spec, it is ok to hide them via CSS "display: none;". See "Hiding an ad unit" at the bottom of this page: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893?hl=en

Comment: There is no such section at that URL at the moment.